# PrimeVue3 Menubar set item to align right

Tags: vuejs3, menubar, primevue

I have a prime vue menubar with 3 tabs that align to the left

HTML

```
<Menubar :model="items" />
```

.vue file

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            items: [
                {
                   label:'Users',
                   icon:'pi pi-fw pi-user',

                },
                {
                   label:'Events',
                   icon:'pi pi-fw pi-calendar',
                  },

                {
                   label:'Settings',
                   icon:'pi pi-fw pi-cog'
                }
             ]
        }
    }
}
```

I want to move the settings tab to the right how would I do this? I tried adding to below the settings label. There is no examples in the docs

```
style:{'margin-right': 'auto'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's a bit late, but just faced this problem today.

One way of doing it would be to set some CSS styles to modify the original `.p-menubar-button` and `.p-menubar-root-list`:

```
.p-menubar-root-list, .p-menubar-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

This will force the items to be on the rigth. But be careful because it does not work if you are using the `end` template (or at least for the quick test I did, it was not working).

Answer (score 0):

You could't use the templating option:

```
<Menubar :model="items">
    <template #end>
        Settings
    </template>
</Menubar>
```

And remove `'settings'` from `items` but then you have to build the way you like.
Maybe a Button which opens a Menu on click

Comment: If this is the only solution the restrictiveness kind of sucks.

Comment: you could use the template #item and have to redo the apperance how you like them.
There you could use a parent div with display flex and justify-content: space-between and rap your menu items in two divs, one for the right side one for the left.

I had a simmular problem with the MenuBar Component so I just created my own component using the Menu component here is a gist for that:

https://gist.github.com/GypsyyCode/7f03dff4b86b54a965a2f84b9b631537

Comment: @Fabian_Lehmann I guess that is a solution. I was expecting to right/ left align items like a simplified version of a bootstrap navbar in the .vue file